# Unit Testing Prism Navigation Callbacks

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am running into a situation where on a view, I have 2 content regions and I want to unit test navigation away from the parent view. Before I navigate from this view I want to verify that both of the views being displayed in the content regions will allow me to navigate. To do this, all three view models for the views implement the `IConfirmNavigationRequest` interface.

For my main view, the `ConfirmNavigationRequest` call looks similiar to this where `RegionManager` is an implementation of `IRegionManager`:

```
public void ConfirmNavigationRequest(NavigationContext navigationContext, Action<bool> continuationCallback)
{
    /* setup code */
    RegionManager.RequestNavigate("regionA",
        new Uri("viewA, UriKind.Relative), ViewACallback,
        navigationResult?.Context?.Parameters);
}

private void ViewACallback(NavigationResult navigationResult)
{
    if(!navigationResult.Result ?? false) return;
    /*Some Code */
    RegionManager.RequestNavigate("regionB",
        new Uri("viewB, UriKind.Relative), ViewBCallback,
        navigationResult?.Context?.Parameters);
}
private void ViewBCallback(NavigationResult navigationResult)
{
    /* some logic */
}
```

With a mocked instance of `IRegionManager` I am able to mock the region request callbacks and implement unit tests. The issue I have is that every step further in the chain I am ending up with duplicate code from the previous tests. It is giving off code smell all over the place and I am just looking on how to clean this up.

My current thought is to abstracting the callbacks into their own classes with interfaces and being able to mock the chain that way, but that seems like a lot of overhead. Another thought was exposing the callbacks as internal and verifying that the callbacks passed on the `RequestNavigate` calls were to the correct callback and then testing those independently. This seemed cleaner to me, but that would be the only reason to expose these as internals.

Just looking for some thoughts or direction to some articles on how to properly unit test callbacks in a scenario like this.

Comment: What about the idea of using an Action for the callbacks? You are just unit testing the `ConfirmNavigationRequest` in your case, right? Do you care if the callback actually runs? This may be an interesting place to get an idea how to unit test something like this: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/a60d38013c02b60807e9287db9ba7f7506af0e84/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf.Tests/Regions/RegionNavigationServiceFixture.new.cs.

Comment: @R.Richards Would using an action as a property be similar to exposing the current method callbacks as internal?  I care about unit testing the logic inside of the callbacks. I currently fake the callbacks with Moq the code gets messy with the nested callbacks.

Comment: No, I don't think so. What I pointed you to won't really help with that. This is starting to seem like UI testing.